# python 2.7: scraping tables from a website

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I am probably doing my scraping incorrectly given I know little programming but I would like to know how I scrape data from an html table in python and associate it with its *own* class...I don't really know what Im doing so here is an example:

```
<div class="example">
    <a href="/example/thisexample">
      <span class="name">Product name</span>
    </a>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="odd"> Some data </tr>
          <tr class="even"> Some data </tr>
          <tr class="odd"> Some data </tr>
          <tr class="even"> Some data </tr>
          <tr class="odd"> More data</tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

So far Im able collect the data using lxml and place it in a list, however, the webpage contains many classes (like example) and all have different tables with more or less rows than above. I would like the data from these tables to be associated with the class aka here the product name...
Sorry if this makes little sense, I am new to this and havent touched python except for an intro class a couple years ago

Comment: Show us the expected output plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you store the data in lists, but you wanted them to be associated with the classes you get from the HTML?
If I am understanding correctly, store them as a dictionary:

stuff = {}

stuff['class name #1'] = ['data thing #1 from table in class', 'data thing #2 from table in class', .... 'data thing #3 from table in class']
.
.
.
stuff['class name #n'] = ....

this way your "stuff" dictionary will store the things in a relational way, thus you associated what is in what by have keys to those things

does that make sense? is that what you are asking?

more about dictionaries [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: A dictionary sounds good,  I'll look into it when I get back from work tonight,  however what I would like is for the data in my lost to automatically be assigned to the (dictionary?) if that makes sense. The site has many class each with a table but not all have the same amount of rows,  so how can I tell Python that the dictionary is to contain that many pieces of data? Because as of now I have one list containing all the data on the page,  or should I change my code to try and get the data in individual lists for each table? If so how can I get that as the table and class have repeating nam

Comment: well a dictionary adds a key to it whenever you specify, then each key can contain a list, and lists in python don't need a specific size.  So in sudoish code: make a dict: dict = {} ...... for each class add a key to a list: dict['class name'] = []......for each row in table you want to add, dict['class name'].append(row).... does that help?

Comment: I'll see what I can do! Thx for the help!